# CSS | El mapa no rellena el vertical completo de la ventana del navegador

Tags: javascript, css, leaflet

Al insertar un mapa leaflet, he probado darl estilos para ajustar a la vertical de la ventana. Si no le aplico un min-height se reduce a nada, no se ve el mapa. ¿Cómo se debería dar el estilo correcto para que tome el vertical completo de la ventana del navegador?

Actulmente de ve así:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Estilos CSS:**

```
<style>
html, body {
  width: 100%;
}
#map {
  width: 100%;
  min-height:850px;
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podes usar la unidad **vh** (Viewport Height) que es básicamente relativa al alto de la pantalla donde se este mirando.
Podes ponerle al elemento contenedor del mapa `height: 100vh;` y va a tener la misma altura que la pantalla.

PD: seguramente vas a tener que restar los margenes fijos con [calc()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/calc()) para que no salga un scroll con algo como `height: calc(100vh - navBarHeight);` donde `navBarHeight` es la altura de tu navBar.

En tu caso algo asi:

```
#map {
    width: 100%;
    height: calc(100vh - 60px);
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
```

Comment: Es perfecto, muchas gracias.